# Often Used Identity Management Technology Stack

Tags: web-services, oauth, architecture, ldap, shiro

I understand that Identity Management can be done in multiple ways, using multiple protocols, depending on one's needs. However, the more I read about various Security Frameworks and Protocols, the more I get confused as to where and when to use them. My need is that I need a robust central Identity Management System that manages Authentication and Authorisation for a host of web applications that might query it. Also, I am looking for such a structure that can be progressively used for SSO (Single Sign On) when the software scales. What are the common technology stacks used worldwide for such identity management systems? How technologies and protocols like LDAP, Apache Shiro, OAuth, CAS fit into all these; i.e what roles do they play? Are they complimentary technologies or interchangeable? Do some of them perform same functions, what are the merits and demerits of using them?

I know I am asking a number of questions and a lot of information but I could not find any good resources that could give me the "bigger picture" for such a requirement. Any help, any sources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Authentication and Authorization, you should check [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/), which is *"a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol"*. The following is an excerpt from [the FAQ page](http://openid.net/connect/faq/).

```
(Identity, Authentication) + OAuth 2.0 = OpenID Connect
```

In general, a web service that manages its own end-users and provides Web APIs to allow third-party applications to make use of the web service consists of the following three roles.

1. **Authentication**
2. **Authorization**
3. **Resource Management**

**Authentication** deals with information about *"who one is"*. Solutions related to user management belong to this area. [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) and CAS (Central Authentication Service) you mentioned are related to authentication. Apache Shiro PMC Chair is a founder of [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/), which offers *"The User Management API"*.

**Authorization** deals with information about *"who grants what permissions to whom"*. [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) (OAuth 2.0) is the industry standard for authorization.

**Resource management** deals with user data. Solutions to host data are related to this area. In the context of OAuth 2.0, endpoints (Web APIs) that provide access to resources are called *"protected resource endpoints"*. [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) lists three ways to present an access token to a protected resource endpoint.

These roles are often implemented in a monolithic way, but if you are aware of the differences among the roles, your confusion will disappear.

It is often heard that entry-level engineers confuse authorization with authentication. Some solutions such as [OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) and [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) that use OAuth for authentication (not authorization) may make such engineers more confused although the solutions are great. Solutions such as [Authlete](https://www.authlete.com/) that are dedicated to authorization only set authorization apart from authentication. Engineers may be able to learn the difference between authorization and authentication from the software architecture of Authlete.

Comment: Thanks for the concise yet useful answer. I think, I have a much better sense of things now. When you say, Resource Management, is that where you refer to technologies like say LDAP (or even an RDBMS for that matter) where you can store user data? If I understand correctly, you listed the three things to demarcate between services (Authentication, Authorization - modelled on protocols like OAuth etc) and resources?Right?

Comment: LDAP is primarily a directory service but it is often used for user account management. In that sense, LDAP is related to both resource management and authentication. The three roles are concepts which can be used to understand the overall architecture of a service. How to implement them is another different thing. For example, RDBMS can be used to store end-users' credentials (authentication), access tokens (authorization) and pictures posted by end-users (resource management). It is also possible to use cloud APIs such as Stormpath and Authlete instead of RDBMS to implement the three roles.